# How can I quickly clear cookies for a specific site using Safari for Mac?

Tags: browser, safari, web, cookies

I know I can "Reset Safari". I know I can go to Cookies from Preferences and search for a site's cookies and delete those. But is there a faster/easier way to just clear cookies for one site (preferably one that I'm already navigated to)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[There you go!](http://www.vertster.com/blog/2009/07/4-ways-to-quickly-clear-the-cookies-for-just-one-site-or-domain.html)

Clearing a Specific Cookie on Safari: Safari makes you do a little more mousework to get to the listing of cookies in the system, and you have to specify which you want to remove.  To get started, go to the preferences menu, and open the “Security” Options.  Partway down the page is a button labeled “Show Cookies.”  Click this.

[image]

Once you have clicked the “Show Cookies” button, you will be shown a listing of all of the cookies your browser has stored, along with a handy search box.  Type the current domain name into this search to see a listing of cookies set by the current site.  From here, you can select and delete the cookies.

[image]

Comment: Darn I realize you're looking for something simpler probably...

Comment: Nothing bad with a complete answer, really. :)

Comment: Oh Safari doesn't support plugins, that's going to make it hard...

Comment: Note, the Remove All button will do the same thing, once you've entered the domain into the search box.

Comment: this even works on chrome +1

Comment: Safari 9 on El Capitan (OS X 10.11) no longer has this feature in the same place or the same way.


Now you go to Safari / Preferences / Privacy and under the Remove All Website Data... button there's a small Details... button.  When you click on that you can see the list of all domain names for which there are Cache, Cookies, and/or Local Storage saved. When you select that domain you can clear all of that data at once or not. There's no way to see individual cookies from Preferences any more, nor a way to remove only one.  But at least you can still do this for a single site.

Answer (score 3):

As @user6297 says in his comment, the above answer no longer works as of El Capitan. You now need to go to `Preferences` > `Privacy` > `Details` as shown in the image. Note that the `Details` button might take a moment to appear.

[image]

Then enter the domain in the Search box, select the item you want to remove, and click `Remove`.

Answer (score 1):

use [Safari Cookies](http://www.sweetpproductions.com/safaricookies/index.htm) Tool

Comment: the Safari Cookies tool is apparently dead.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the preferences menu, and open the “Security” Options.  Part way down the page is a button labeled “Show Cookies.”  Click this.

[image]

http://www.ehow.com/how_4839198_cookies-safari-mac-computer-beginners.html

source : http://www.vertster.com/blog/2009/07/4-ways-to-quickly-clear-the-cookies-for-just-one-site-or-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

To clear all cookies, you can setup a keyboard shortcut (Option-Cmd-R) to Safari → Reset Safari

Answer (score 0):

If someone using **OS X or later** comes across this post then you know that clearing cookies for a specific site has become much harder now.

Here are the steps as of Dec. 2023:

1. Go to the `Privacy` tab under `Settings`. Shortcut: Cmd+,
   [image: Image of safari settings privacy window]
2. Click on `Manage Website Data...` after which you will see a list of all websites that have cookies stored on your browser. The sites like google have more than just cookies :wink:
   [image: Image of a window with a list of websites]
3. There you can select an individual site and click on `Remove` on the bottom-left of the window.